# My topbar duplicates since adding axios and importing the user image with axios and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I would like to know why my "topbar" is duplicated when I only want one. And it's since I did my import of the user image via axios and added the .map in the return. I really don't understand why if someone could help me that would be nice. Thanks in advance
[image]

```
import "./topbar.css"
import { Search } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"


function Home() {

const [user, setPosts] = useState([])



useEffect(() => {
    console.log("chargement ok")
    const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
    'http://localhost:4200/api/user/')
    setPosts(result.data)
    }
    fetchData();
}, [])


    return (
        <Fragment>
            { user
            ? user.map((users,topbar) => ( <div key={topbar} className="topBarContainer">
                            <div className="topBarLeft">
                                <span className="logo">Groupomania</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="topBarCenter">
                                <div className="searchBar">
                                    <Search className="searchIcon" />
                                    <input placeholder="Vous cherchez quelque chose ?" className="searchInput" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="topBarRight">
                                <div className="topBarLinks">
                                    <span className="topBarLink">Page d'acceuil</span>
                                    <span className="topBarLink">Deconnexion</span>
                                </div>
                                <img src={users.picture} alt="Photo de profil de l'utilisateur" className="topBarImg" />
                            </div>
                        </div>))
                    : (<p></p>)
            }
        </Fragment>
        )
}
    
export default Home
```

Comment: What does http://localhost:4200/api/user/ return? Is it a list of all the users? If it is then when using the map  function it will render the top bar for every user that you have in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it may be because of your key.
Some patterns to fix first:

- `const [user, setPosts] = useState([])` -> `const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])`
- you don't have to use the word Fragment:  -> <>
- Normally in a `.map` params are used like this `posts.map((post, index) => ...)`
- `posts ? post.map(...) : null`

Edit: of course you have to remove your topbar from your `.map(...)`

Now try with a better `key` than "topbard" that is the index in the array ... try `post.id` that should be uniq

Edit solution:

```
import "./topbar.css";
import { Search } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("chargement ok");
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:4200/api/user/");
      setUser(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="topBarContainer">
      <div className="topBarLeft">
        <span className="logo">Groupomania</span>
      </div>
      <div className="topBarCenter">
        <div className="searchBar">
          <Search className="searchIcon" />
          <input
            placeholder="Vous cherchez quelque chose ?"
            className="searchInput"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="topBarRight">
        <div className="topBarLinks">
          <span className="topBarLink">Page d'acceuil</span>
          <span className="topBarLink">Deconnexion</span>
        </div>
        {user && <img
          src={user.picture}
          alt="Photo de profil de l'utilisateur"
          className="topBarImg"
        />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: like that ? : https://paste.artemix.org/-/hqYC87

because it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, but you are still iterating through "posts" and are rendering a top bar.
I think I understand what you wan to to achieve here ...

Answer (score 1):

As the map is rendering the `topbar` for every user, you get as many `topbars` as there are users.
The `map` function should be inside the top bar container div.

```
<div key={key} className="topBarContainer">
  { user.map(...) }
</div>
```

Comment: Hello I tried but it still doesn't work can you show me how? Thanks

Comment: @Tewho, it seems there are multiple users. Which user would you use for `users.picture`?

Comment: I only want the logged in user

Comment: How do you identify that from the user list?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your are making the topbar inside the loop,So you are getting a topbar per user.